# select2 pseudo-disabled entries

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have a select2-dropdown and need some values pseudo-disabled depending on their value.
By "pseudo disabled" I mean to be able to call a function onclick, but then prevent default.

So I did this:

```
$myselect2.on("select2:selecting", function(e){
    if($myselect2.val()=='proOnly'){
        proOnly();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

but of course, that cannot work as per documentation (https://select2.github.io/examples.html) the event is fired prior to selecting (which I need to prevent).

I'm stuck.

I just tried this, which works as expected, but is really ugly:

```
$myselect2.on("select2:select", function(e){
    if($myselect2.val()=='proOnly'){
        $myselect2.select2("val", "-1");
        proOnly();
    }
});
```

Comment: What does your `proOnly()` function look like?

Comment: at the moment, it's just alerting...

Comment: Oh I see.. Could you try this? ... `if ($myselect2.val() == 'proOnly') { $myselect2.select2().enable(false); proOnly(); }` ...

Comment: thanks, but no, this cannot work. If I put it inside "selecting", the val() is not yet set to the selected, if I setit to "select", it's to late...

Comment: The event that is triggered should include some extra data if you check `evt.params`. One of the parameters passed in will be the data object that is going to be selected, and you can check the `id` there. I'll write this up as a more complete answer in a few hours.